# Splitting principle for real vector bundles with $w_i=0$, $0<i<2^r$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Is the following true/known?

Let $E$ be a (real) vector bundle over a compact CW-complex $X$.
 Suppose that
 $w_i(E)=0$ for $0<i<2^r$.
 Then
 there exist
 a space $Y$ and a map $f\colon Y\to X$ such that

(1)
 $f^*\colon H^*(X;\mathbb F_2)\to H^*(Y;\mathbb F_2)$ is injective;

(2)
 for some $k\geqslant0$,
 the vector bundle $f^*(E)\oplus(k)$ over $Y$ is isomorphic
 to a sum of vector bundles of the form
 $$
 (L_1\oplus(1))\otimes\dots\otimes(L_{r+1}\oplus(1)),
 $$
 where $L_s$ are line bundles
 (and $(n)$ denotes the $n$-dimensional trivial bundle).

Comment: I must be missing something here, but isn't this implied by the usual splitting principle for real bundles (without needing any assumptions on the $w_i$)?

Comment: A bundle of the form $(L_1\oplus(1))\otimes\dots\otimes(L_{r+1}\oplus(1))$ has $w_i=0$ for $0<i<2^r$ (if I did not mistake in this calculation). It follows that sums of such bundles also have this property. So the assumption about $w_i(E)$ cannot be omitted.

Comment: Do you mean that (n) denotes the $-n$ dimensional trivial (virtual) bundle?

Comment: Do you know this in the case $r=1$ and X is the Grassmannian of oriented 2-planes (in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if you insist on compact CW-complexes)? That seems like a good test case.

Comment: @user43326:
$(n)$ stands for the $n$-dimensional trivial bundle.
$n$ is assumed non-negative here.

We can admit negative $k$ and ask for equality in $KO(Y)$
(instead of isomorphism),
it is an equivalent problem.

Comment: @Chris Schommer-Pries: Proof for $r=1$ and $\operatorname{dim}E=2$:
 by the usual splitting principle,
 there is a map $f\colon Y\to X$
 injective on $H^*({-};\mathbb F_2)$ and
 such that $f^*(E)=L\oplus M$,
 where $L$ and $M$ are line bundles.
 From $w_1(E)=0$,
 it follows that
 $L\cong M$.
 Using $L\otimes L\cong(1)$,
 we get
 $
 (L\oplus(1))\otimes(L\oplus(1))
 \cong
 L\oplus L\oplus(2)
 \cong
 L\oplus M\oplus(2)
 \cong
 f^*(E)\oplus(2)
 $.

Comment: Is there any constraint concerning $dim(E)$ and $r$? For $r=0$, the assertion would be trivially true for line bundles, and equally trivially false for bundles of greater dimension.

Comment: @user43326:
 Note that
 $f^*(E)\oplus(k)$ is asked to be isomorphic to a SUM of tensor products
 (not a single tensor product).
 The statement for $r=0$ is true,
 it follows from the usual splitting principle.
 Namely,
 there is a map $f\colon Y\to X$
 injective on $H^*({-};\mathbb F_2)$ and
 such that $f^*(E)\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^kL_i$,
 where
 $L_i$ are line bundles and
 $k=\operatorname{dim} E$.
 Thus $f^*(E)\oplus(k)\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^k(L_i\oplus(1))$.

Comment: @SemenPodkorytov So the $r$ in the hypothesis of vanishing of Stiefel-Whiteney classes and the $r$ that appear in the index for different line bundles are different?

Comment: @user43326: $r$ is the same everywhere. Each tensor product has $r+1$ factors. If we take the sum of, say, $p$ tensor products, then we need $p(r+1)$ line bundles.

Comment: @SemenPodkorytov Ok, I got it now, sorry and thanks.